# Update row to specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CTE_product as follow:

| Customer | ProductName | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | 2 | 2.00 |
| A | Banana | 3 | 1.00 |

And a table Total:

| CustomerName | Apple | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4.00 | 3.00 |

What I want is to calculate the **Total Price** of each Product in the CTE and update its value to the corresponding column in table Total

Here is my query I've tried:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Apple = CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Apple' THEN cte.Quantity * cte.Price ELSE 0 END,
    t.Banana = CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Banana' THEN cte.Quantity * cte.Price ELSE 0 END
FROM Total t
INNER JOIN CTE_product cte ON cte.CustomerName = t.CustomerName
```

With this query, only column Apple has value.

Comment: Something about your total table does not seem right ... is every fruit really a separate column?

Comment: Yes, sure. Because of some privacy, I have to fix my data column's name. But the structure is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method might be two joins:

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.Apple = COALESCE(a.Quantity * a.Price, t.Apple),
        t.Banana = COALESCE(b.Quantity * b.Price, t.Banana)
FROM Total t LEFT JOIN
     CTE_product a
     ON a.CustomerName = t.CustomerName AND
        a.ProductName = 'Apple' LEFT JOIN
     CTE_product b
     ON b.CustomerName = t.CustomerName AND
        b.ProductName = 'Banana'
WHERE a.CustomerName IS NOT NULL OR b.CustomerName IS NOT NULL;
```

Note:  This assumes that the CTE has only one row per customer and product.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the update essentially done row by row, since in `JOIN`ed data apples and bananas are at different rows.

You need to "skip" update for column that is not a subject for update like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET
  t.Apple =  CASE
               WHEN ProductName = 'Apple'
               THEN cte.Quantity * cte.Price
               ELSE t.Apple
             END,
  t.Banana = CASE
               WHEN ProductName = 'Banana'
               THEN cte.Quantity * cte.Price
               ELSE t.Banana
             END
FROM Total t
INNER JOIN CTE_product cte ON cte.CustomerName = t.CustomerName
```

Or pivot your data before update:

```
with cte_pivoted as (
  select
    CustomerName,
    [Apple] as Apple,
    [Banana] as Banana
  from CTE_product
  pivot(
    sum(Quantity*Price) for ProductName in ([Apple], [Banana])
  ) as p
)

UPDATE t
  SET t.Apple = coalesce(cte.apple, 0), t.Banana = coalesce(cte.Banana, 0)
FROM Total t
INNER JOIN cte_pivoted cte
  ON cte.CustomerName = t.CustomerName
```

Of course both statements expect you have only one row for single product and customer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the 1st solution didn't work. The Banana column returns null only

Comment: @NekoMi Looks like you have nulls in your CTE in `quantity` or `price` columns. You can check this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=30e2a249a44f3c403e5ecc410d7d3b15)

Comment: yep. But in your fiddle, the `Banana` column  is not changed or calculated. It shows the default value

Comment: @NekoMi Yes, but what is your requrement? Should it be 0 if there's no `'Banana'` rows? Then you need to identify if there was a `Banana` row, which is available via `PIVOT` query and null handling. I've updated it to set 0 instead of `null` in case there's no rows for some products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sub-query(conditional aggregation) in the `FROM` clause to calculate the banana and apple total values as follows:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.Apple = cte.apple,
    t.Banana = cte.banana
FROM Total t
INNER JOIN 
  (select customername,
          sum(CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Apple' THEN cte.Quantity * cte.Price ELSE 0 END) as apple,
          sum(CASE WHEN ProductName = 'Banana' THEN cte.Quantity * cte.Price ELSE 0 END) as banana
    from CTE_product) cte ON cte.CustomerName = t.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pivot the data in your CTE and update from there:

```sql
WITH cte_Product AS
(...)
, cte_Total AS
(
    SELECT      [Customer], [ProductName]
                , [Quantity] * [Price] AS [TotalSalePrice]
    FROM        cte_Product
)
, cte_Pivot AS
(
    SELECT          [Customer], [Apple], [Banana]
    FROM            cte_Total
    PIVOT           ( SUM ( [TotalSalePrice] )
        FOR         [ProductName] IN ( [Apple], [Banana] ) ) AS pvt
)
UPDATE          t
SET             [Apple]     = p.[Apple]
                , [Banana]  = p.[Banana]
FROM            cte_Pivot AS p
    INNER JOIN  Total AS t
        ON      p.[Customer] = t.[CustomerName] ;
GO
```